# Codeception. Insert multiple records

Tags: codeception

Is it possible to insert several records to the DB in Codeception? This code doesn't work but maybe there is another option.

```
$this->tester->haveRecord('vacations',
            ['destination' => $this->"Place 1"],
            ['destination' => $this->"Place 2"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting it into two worked perfectly.

```
$this->tester->haveRecord('vacations',
            ['destination' => $this->"Place 1"]);
```

```
$this->tester->haveRecord('vacations',
            ['destination' => $this->"Place 2"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using foreach? I'd do something like this:

```
$places = ["Place 1", "Place 2"];

foreach ($places as $place) {
  $this->tester->haveRecord('vacations', ['destination' => $place]); 
}
```